# Difference in HDD for PC and for (PC and Mac)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, mac

I want to buy an external HDD. But I found that some HDD are specified as **'for PC'**, some as **'PC or Mac'** and some other as **'PC and Mac'**.

Since I have both Macbook and PC so, I would like to connect the HDD with both Mac OS as well as Windows.

I already have an exiting HDD and as far as I remember, I simply formatted it in "MS-DOS (FAT)" format and I can use it with both Mac/PC.

**QUESTION:** Is it just a marketing strategy or is there any particular benefit to buy an HDD which is specified as "`for Mac and PC`".

**FOR EXAMPLE** Can I use this HDD to transfer files from Mac and PC?

[image: C]

Answer (score 3):

There is no mechanical or electrical difference in the device itself that would prevent it working on a PC or Mac; the advert statement is likely just an indication of what the drive has been partitioned/formatted as already

I would raise the point though, that you seem to be planning a purchase of a drive that far exceeds the size that windows will format as FAT32, so you'll have to defer to a third party utility. You may still run into trouble saving single files more than 4 gigabytes. You may wish to consider exFAT instead

Comment: Nice answer, and kudos for mentioning the file system issue.

Comment: Thanks, then I will format the drive as "exFat" using Utilities program in Mac OS.